# How do I include contacts when searching in Google Maps?

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-5

When I search for "Joe" in the Google Maps application, I'd like it to include "Joe Smith" from my Google contacts. How might I make this happen?

I'm using CyanogenMod 11-20140604-NIGHTLY-hammerhead (on a Nexus 5, "hammerhead").

Comment: +1 as I didn't even know this was a feature of Google Maps app. I've posted an answer below. Nice to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha! The trick is to enable [Web History](https://history.google.com/history/settings?hl=en). After doing so, I now see addresses for my Contacts (my "People") in Maps when I search for them by name.

Comment: +1 sorry I didn't get back to you sooner, I was asleep! Glad you resolved it. I will add to my answer for the sake of completeness. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The below is from  [Google Support](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3131570?hl=en-GB) and it also includes iPad / iPhone support for anyone that may be relevant to.

**Search for a contact’s address**

**Google Contacts**

See home and work addresses for friends, family and colleagues in your Google Contacts on the map. Here's how to find a contact's address on the map:

1.Open the  Google Maps app.

2.To sign in, touch the [image]  person icon next to the search box. If your 
[image]  person icon is filled in, you’re already signed in.

3.In the search box at the top, start typing a name. `**Suggested contacts will appear in the search results.**

4.Touch a result to see that person's address on the map.

> If your account is managed by your company or another organisation, you can't currently search for contacts.

As per the OP finding the solution himself, you need to enable [Web History](https://history.google.com/history/settings?hl=en)  for this functionality to work.

Comment: Does this work for you? I should have mentioned that I did see and followed these instructions, but I still don't get personal results. I'm using Google to manage my contacts (by I do have contacts from other accounts as well, such as Skype and Exchange).